# How to use SSH and remote web server with a Mac

Tags: ssh, terminal, cpanel

This is the first time I'm doing this. I generated a key on my Mac and I have id_dsa, id_dsa.pub. I imported public key into my cPanel. After reading a few tutorials and blogs I'm still lost. How can I connect to my server from this point?

Answer (score 1):

To connect, you would do this: `ssh -l yourusername the.server.address` from Terminal.

For instance, your username is kira, and your server is my.server.net:

`ssh -l kira my.server.net`

You will be prompted for your password, and the you're in (provided you enter a correct password of course)

Comment: When I try this I get Permission denied (publickey). Is it better to generate key from cPanel or from terminal and then importing that key into cPanel?

Comment: Generate keys on your machine, and then import them to the cPanel server.

Comment: When I tried that for several times I stuck on connecting, always permision denied error. Now I tried other way, from cPanel to osx and I got "Shell access is not enabled on your account!
If you need shell access please contact support."

Comment: Did you actually get shell access explicitly enabled...?

Comment: Hosting provider says my package has SSH within

Comment: It's worth mentioning to them that you are getting the error message saying "if you need shell access please contact support..."

Comment: I don't know why is that. I tried to go over whole procees again and now I get error "Received disconnect from xxx: Too many authentication failures for xxx"

Comment: That's the cPanel sever disallowing anymore connection attempts, it likely looks like you are "attacking" it with so many consecutive failed connection attempts. Support will unblock that for you - which is first thing you need to do now, get it unblocked. I feel your pain, and hope they are pretty quick on support!

Comment: I think they won't see my ticket for a while. It's night here. But this error means that I finally managed to set everything? When they unblock it I should connect normally?

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track yes, do update when support have unblocked you. Very happy to help further.

Comment: Hosting provider ignored my tickets so I immediately changed my hosting provider. Tired of their incompetence. Now everything works...

Comment: Nicely done! Glad everything is working for you. Hope I helped somewhat!